# SQL Query with combining MAX() and SUM() aggregates

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, max

I have tried looking into different topics over here and in other forums but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

What I'm trying to achieve is "Display the net sales (in dollars) of the Product Line with the highest revenue for that Customer. Use a heading of: Best Sales. Format as $999,999.99.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT cc.CustID, cc.CompanyName, cc.ContactName, pl.pl_id,to_char((sum(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-discount))), '$9,999,999.99') as rev
     FROM corp.customers cc JOIN corp.orders co ON (cc.CustID=co.CustID)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN corp.order_details od ON (co.orderID=od.orderID)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN corp.products cp ON (od.ProductID=cp.ProductID)
     LEFT OUTER JOIN corp.product_lines pl ON (cp.pl_id=pl.pl_id)
     GROUP BY cc.CustID, cc.CompanyName, cc.ContactName, pl.pl_id
     HAVING sum(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-discount))=
    ( 
       SELECT max(sum(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-discount)))
       FROM corp.customers cc JOIN corp.orders co ON (cc.CustID=co.CustID)
       JOIN corp.order_details od ON (co.orderID=od.orderID)
       JOIN corp.products cp ON (od.ProductID=cp.ProductID)
       JOIN corp.product_lines pl ON (cp.pl_id=pl.pl_id)
       GROUP BY cc.CustID, cc.CompanyName, cc.ContactName, pl.pl_id);
```

This gives me only one output indicating the highest revenue of all customers, but I would like it to display the highest revenue according to each of the product line for that customer.

The result is shown below.

```
CustID  | Company Name  | Contact Name  | PL_ID | Revenue
QUICK   | QUICK-Stop    | Horst Kloss   | 1     | $37,161.63
```

I would like it to show something like.

```
CustID  | Company Name  | Contact Name  | PL_ID | Revenue
QUICK   | QUICK-Stop    | Horst Kloss   | 1     | $37,161.63
QS      | QUICK-Start   | Clark Stone   | 2     | $50,000.00
QUI     | QUICK         | Mary Haynes   | 1     | $60,000.00
QShelf  | QUICK-Shelf   | Doreen Lucas  | 4     | $35,161.63
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this for Oracle? Or MySQL? Or SQL Server?

Comment: Hi, this is Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: please provide sample data with expected result in table structure

Comment: I have updated the post with the result I get with the code as well as what I would hope the result would show

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

This query uses your original query, a rank() function to order by your rev column, and a selection to only get the highest rev. This will give multiple rows if you have multiple rows with the same rev value. Change rank() to row_number() if you only want one.

You could also use CTE instead of the nested queries, wont make any difference.

```
select CustID, CompanyName, ContactName, pl_id, rev from (
select CustID, CompanyName, ContactName, pl_id, to_char(rev, '$9,999,999.99') as rev,
    rank() over(order by rev desc) r
from (
    SELECT cc.CustID, cc.CompanyName, cc.ContactName, pl.pl_id,
        sum(od.unitprice*od.quantity*(1-discount)) as rev
    FROM corp.customers cc JOIN corp.orders co ON (cc.CustID=co.CustID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN corp.order_details od ON (co.orderID=od.orderID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN corp.products cp ON (od.ProductID=cp.ProductID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN corp.product_lines pl ON (cp.pl_id=pl.pl_id)
    GROUP BY cc.CustID, cc.CompanyName, cc.ContactName, pl.pl_id
) q
) q2 where r=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide us with sample input data for your tables, I've knocked up a simple example that you can hopefully use to amend your query:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, 1 id2, 10 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID, 1 id2, 20 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID, 2 id2, 30 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID, 2 id2, 40 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 1 id2, 50 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 2 id2, 60 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 3 id2, 60 val FROM dual)
SELECT ID,
       id2,
       max_sum_val
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               id2,
               SUM(val) sum_val,
               MAX(SUM(val)) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) max_sum_val
        FROM   sample_data
        GROUP BY ID, id2)
WHERE  sum_val = max_sum_val;

        ID        ID2 MAX_SUM_VAL
---------- ---------- -----------
         1          2          70
         2          2          60
         2          3          60
```

This will display all id2 values that have the same sum(val) that's the highest. If you don't want to display all tied rows, you can used the `row_number()` analytic function instead:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, 1 id2, 10 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID, 1 id2, 20 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID, 2 id2, 30 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 1 ID, 2 id2, 40 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 1 id2, 50 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 2 id2, 60 val FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 3 id2, 60 val FROM dual)
SELECT ID,
       id2,
       max_sum_val
FROM   (SELECT ID,
               id2,
               SUM(val) sum_val,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SUM(val) DESC, id2) rn
        FROM   sample_data
        GROUP BY ID, id2)
WHERE  rn = 1;

        ID        ID2 MAX_SUM_VAL
---------- ---------- -----------
         1          2          70
         2          2          60
```

---

ETA:

That means your query would end up something like:

```
SELECT custid,
       companyname,
       contactname,
       pl_id,
       to_char(rev, '$9,999,999.99') rev
FROM   (SELECT cc.custid,
               cc.companyname,
               cc.contactname,
               pl.pl_id,
               SUM(od.unitprice * od.quantity * (1 - discount)) AS rev,
               MAX(SUM(od.unitprice * od.quantity * (1 - discount))) OVER (PARTITION BY cc.custid) max_rev
        FROM   corp.customers cc
               INNER JOIN corp.orders co ON (cc.custid = co.custid)
               LEFT OUTER JOIN corp.order_details od ON (co.orderid = od.orderid)
               LEFT OUTER JOIN corp.products cp ON (od.productid = cp.productid)
               LEFT OUTER JOIN corp.product_lines PL ON (cp.pl_id = pl.pl_id)
        GROUP  BY cc.custid,
                  cc.companyname,
                  cc.contactname,
                  pl.pl_id)
WHERE  rev = max_rev;
```